# Looking for a simple Mailing List / Forum implementation for/in Python/Plone

Tags: plone, forum, mailing-list, mailman

I am in the process to set up a new site with Plone, and I am looking for a simple mailing list / forum implementation.

I am aware of Mailman, of course. But what I am looking for is some *hybrid solution* which shows *discussion threads* in a *web UI* as well as in a users *mail client* and sends replies subscribers.

Or course, the UI should be managed and integrated in plone.

I'd be happy, if someone could point at the right direction. I'm lost.

For example: Looking at plone org, I see some products based on mailman, which might do the job, but no real contender. Some of the products on plone.org don't even have a description. Searching for mailman shows up kupu in the list. Clicking on this product I see the description: "The most recent released version of Kupu may be found here." Err. Yes, obviously. And what does it do?!?

Is there any simple discussion forum / mailing list product available for plone?

Comment: upvoted back to 0. I'm sorry to see people down voting without comment, I hope that's not just a lazy way of saying you don't think forums should be done in Plone.

Comment: @Danimal: People from Python tag tend to be overmoderating StackOverflow rule nazis. I recommend all Plone questions should be asked without Python tag.

Comment: Just started a new addon, currently needs some more love for the categorizations, but that shouldn't be too far away. Reply via mail works. Any feedback very welcome: http://github.com/ida/adi.forumail

Answer (score 5):

I think the widely accepted answer to this in the Plone community is that Plone is probably not the right tool to build a large forum.  This is up for debate, and to be honest I'm not sure myself, but I do know that [community.plone.org](http://community.plone.org) uses Discourse.

Ploneboard is there of course (as @GhitaB has mentioned), but it's not getting a lot of work done on it at the moment.  You could also build your own to suit your own requirements, and you might find the Dexterity based [collective.ploneboard](https://github.com/tisto/collective.ploneboard) a useful starting point for that.

Also, Plone has [built in comments functionality](http://pythonhosted.org/plone.app.discussion/) which I guess doesn't cover so many features, but could do most of what you are looking for. People do also use a [Disqus integration](https://plone.org/products/collective.disqus) into plone.

Regarding searching for products - you are better off searching [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/) than plone.org.  And Kupu is a rich text editor like TinyMCE - definitely not what you are looking for (but perhaps compatible with mailman?).

All the best, I'd be interested to hear which direction you end up taking.

Comment: I voted your answer because Ploneboard seems to be a little abandonware. There is now a bug for more than 30 comments in a discussion that make this unusable. https://github.com/collective/Products.Ploneboard/issues/46

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll post an update once we've made a decision.

Answer (score 3):

Ploneboard may help you. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Ploneboard

Some features:

- Forum: Show all recent activity, Show all unanswered
- Category state: Make free for all, Make moderated, Make private, Require membership to post
- Conversation state: Active, Lock

Answer (score 1):

the [coactivate.org project](http://www.coactivate.org/projects/opencore) is based on plone and has an integration for a mailing list using Listen ([found here](http://www.coactivate.org/projects/opencore/getting-started)).
you might browse the project resources on github or ask the contributors to find out how they do the mailing-list integration.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few popular options as-a-service

https://www.discourse.org/ (used by e.g. atom.io, by Github, also OSS)

http://muut.com/ (as-a-service, sends mail notification, provides user integration (commercial)

Tons of PHP-based forums. Stay away from those as their security track records are abysmal.

Comment: RoR or PHP isn't what we're after. But muut is an interesting pointer. Thanks for that!